# Offset WCSAxesSubplot from the bottom of the window

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, astropy

I am trying to offset my `WCSAxesSubplot` off the bottom of the plot to allow room for multiple sliders and buttons in `matplotlib`.

However, I have not found anyway to do it.

Currently I am using:

```
ax = plt.subplot(projection = was_data)

scatter = ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, transform=ax.get_transform('fk5'))

image = ax.imshow(image_data, cmap = 'Greys')

figure = plt.gcf()
figure.set_size_inches(5, 7.8)
```

To allow this room for the plots, but this leaves a large margin above the title.

Because `matplotlibs` widget tool does not allow `WCSAxesSubplot` this is the only way that does not crash my script.

Comment: Seems like [`subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) might be what you're looking for, does that work?

Comment: please put your code in code style